# How does giving components a selector help in overriding styles in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

https://ionicframework.com/docs//intro/tutorial/adding-pages/

> Below, we see the HelloIonicPage class. This creates a Page - an Angular component with all Ionic directives already provided, to be loaded using Ionic’s navigation system. Notice that because Pages are meant to be loaded dynamically, they don’t need to have a selector. However, the selector is useful in order to override the default styles on a specific page (see hello-ionic.scss)

**hello-ionic.scss**:

`page-hello-ionic {}`

How does giving the component a selector help in styling the page? I am unable to style using it. Isn't the `:host` selector in Angular used for styling the host component element?

Comment: I don't know Ionic, but I guess it is meant for global styles or styles added to parent components, where you can use the tag as selector. Otherwise it will be just a `<div>`.

Comment: Yeah but it isn't working like that. `:host` selector is working. So I thought it has some other purpose.

Comment: `:host` selector only works from inside the component. From outside the component `:host` won't you buy anything.

Comment: but isn't component style encapsulation the salient feature of Angular? How can we style the parent component from within the component?

Comment: The other way around, when you want to style a child component from a parent or `index.html`.

Comment: oh, got it finally. Thanks :) ❤